# Adding to cookie file via Button using Classic ASP

Tags: button, cookies, asp-classic, click, addition

I'm making a website for pictures and am trying to use cookies for the shoppingcart.
Is it possible to add data to a cookie via a buttonclick?
This is my code:

```
<?
Response.Cookies ("MYCOOKIE").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
Response.Cookies ("MYCOOKIE")[("BgColor")] = "Kibbeling 26 : Sea Warrior's Strike Back "
Response.Cookies ("MYCOOKIE")("Date") = DateTime.Now

Dim MyCookie
Dim MyCookie2
MyCookie = Request.Cookies ("MYCOOKIE")("BgColor")
MyCookie2 = Request.Cookies ("MYCOOKIE")("Date")
Response.Write(MyCookie)
Response.Write(MyCookie2)

%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Cookies</title>
</head>
<body runat="server" id="BodyTag">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why in the world are you writing new code using ancient technology like Classic ASP? Are you aware that it was obsolete over a decade ago?

Comment: I just started a random tutorial I found, so I didn't realy pay attention to that. Thanks for the info I'm supposed to use ASP.net so I guess I'll look for another tutorial first.

Comment: ASP is server sidee code.  If your button is a form submit button then you could add data to your cookies using `Request.Form()` but that's about the only way. ASP.net is also server side. .net web controls have the property runat="server", but they support onclick events, so it feels a bit more like using using an onclick event to trigger client side JavaScript